# Is a two-rowed or one-and-a-half-rowed nav bar a bad look for a website?

Tags: website-design, navigation, menu

I'm currently making a website, though due Wordpress's template and the amount of menu items present, the nav bar is a little longer than I'd like.

I've tried to make the nav bar longer, but ran into Wordpress's limitations. There's a picture of the AS-IS below. Is this ugly or bad for users' expectations? Or should I try to get it down to one line? Or even equally filled on both lines?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem I find is the choice of font face.  For Vlaams, I'd use a grotesk face, or at a minimum a serifed face without a lot of difference in stroke thickness.  Maybe bump the point size a bit, too.

As far as it being multi-lined and not centered, it looks fine to me.  The village's name is nicely placed and clear (is the site for the village itself, or is it for a business with the same name?  My Nederlands/Vlaams is quite rusty)

Comment: Mmhmm, good point. I hadn't considered the choice of font yet. Completely out of my area of expertise. I'll try some fonts out and see what works. The site is for a soccer club, but it's basically 'VillageName soccer club', so I figured just the village name would work.

Answer (score 1):

**Reduce it to one line**. Right now for example, if you click/hover the "Club" element the sub-menu will get above the second line of the menu, which is not much convenient. If the menu doesn't fit in one line:

- When the screen size is "too small for the menu" hide all elements under a button. When clicking it display the elements one over the other (in a modal or overlay div for example).
- Let the menu be scrolled horizontally. In a similar way Google does in phones (this method however, is not very practical for desktop):

[image]

Some resources:

[Material Design - Menus](https://material.google.com/components/menus.html#)

[Material Design - Navigation Drawer](https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#)

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that might be the suggestion, for it is difficult at best with the Wordpress template. I'm considering moving the 'club' template with the dropdown. That might be slightly better.  I think the website/nav bar is already responsive, but i'm gonna double check in a bit.